Как правильно расставить знаки в данном предложении?
Нужна ли запятая перед тире в данном предложении? (Или тире здесь вообще неуместно, а лучше многоточие или просто запятая?)
То есть когда-нибудь, после учебы (,) — хотя и тогда спешить не буду.
Или:
То есть когда-нибудь, после учебы... хотя и тогда спешить не буду.
(Контекст такой:
— А ты мечтаешь выйти замуж?
— Нет, конечно! — как-то слишком бездумно выпалила я. Но попыталась исправиться: — То есть когда-нибудь, после учебы — хотя и тогда спешить не буду.)

В данном предложении возможны следующие знаки: запятая, тире или многоточие.
(1) Запятая ставится, если отношения между частями предложения уступительные:
То есть когда-нибудь, после учебы, хотя и тогда спешить не буду.
(2) В СПП с придаточным уступительным по правилам возможна постановка тире. В этом случае отношения уступительные с добавочным присоединительным значением (обозначение более длительной паузы).
То есть когда-нибудь, после учебы — хотя и тогда спешить не буду.
Розенталь § 38. Тире в сложноподчиненном предложении
1. Тире ставится для интонационного отделения главной части 
сложноподчиненного предложения от придаточной. Чаще всего 
тире употребляется в тех случаях, когда главной части 
предшествует:
3) придаточная уступительная: Пускай, как хотят, тиранят, 
пускай хоть кожу с живой снимут — я воли своей не отдам 
(С.‑Щ.); Сколько бы ни смотреть на море — оно никогда не 
надоест (Кат.).

(3) Но если нужно обозначить паузу в речи, то ставится многоточие:
То есть когда-нибудь, после учебы... хотя и тогда спешить не буду.
Розенталь, § 4. Многоточие
2. Многоточие ставится для указания на перерывы в речи, на 
заминки: В департаменте… но лучше не называть, в каком 
департаменте (Г.).

Единый знак (запятая и тире) не подойдет, так как для для него нужны дополнительные условия.
