Назывное предложение в составе сложного
1)Я не знаю, 2)что со мною.
1)Синцов прикинул, 2)сколько отсюда до Вязьмы…
В данных предложениях придатчоная часть под цифрой 2) не будет являться назывным предложением? Ведь там есть только подлежащее, сказуемое отсутствует.
Пример взяла отсюда:
https://studfile.net/preview/7306656/page:47/
В самом конце там написано:
«Следует отличать назывные предложения в составе сложных, особенно если главный член в них выражается относительным местоимением – союзным словом»
Отличать назывные предложения в составе сложных от чего? От обычных назывных? Вообще будут ли эти предложения СПП?

Комментарий к вопросу
Изучать грамматику желательно по проверенным источникам, которые вызывают доверие. Чтобы получить представление о назывных предложениях в принципе, прочитайте эту тему у Литневской, стр. 81. bookscafe.net/read/… Это материалы для школьников от Грамоты.ру. Всегда желательно сначала изучать базовые (основные) понятия в теме.
Ваши примеры — это эллиптические (или двусоставные неполные) предложения, об этом говорится в справочнике у Розенталя old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93 Они построены по схеме подлежащее — обстоятельство.
Можно посмотреть тему здесь russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/primeryi-nazyivnyih-predlozheniy.html
Назывные предложения следует отличать от неполных двусоставных предложений, в которых может не быть сказуемого, но присутствует дополнение или обстоятельство (группа сказуемого).
Именно эти предложения у Розенталя названы эллиптическими. Сравнить: Ваза на столе (назывное: подлежащее + обст. определение). На столе — ваза (двусоставное неполное).
Сколько км (будет) отсюда до Вязьмы. Разве это назывное предложение?   Подлежащее + обстоятельство, сказуемое подразумевается, двусоставное неполное (эллиптическое) предложение.
Вообще говоря, эта тема (назывные предложения в СПП) совершенно экзотическая, и мне пришлось хорошо подумать, чтобы привести хотя бы один пример.  В составе СПП могут быть номинативные сочетания, но только не назывные предложения.
Недавно встретился пример номинативного сочетания в составе СПП https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/482183/Как-правильно-расставить-знаки-в-данном-предложении

значит на сайте,который я привела в пример есть ошибка? и это не будут назывные предложения в составе сложных?

Я затрудняюсь дать оценку этому сайту, там написаны очень странные вещи. Автор путается в элементарных понятиях, но это моя точка зрения.  Прочитайте тему  в других источниках, и вы сами сможете оценить сказанное тут.

С другой стороны, можно предположить, что в вузе изучают различные варианты классификации односоставных предложений. Но в современном языкознании классический вариант является основным, а все остальное  в любом случае лежит за пределами школы. Поэтому так важно выбрать подходящую учебную литературу. Если недостаточно школьного учебника, то в первую очередь надо ориентироваться на Литневскую.  https://bookscafe.net/read/litnevskaya_elena-russkiy_yazyk_kratkiy_teoreticheskiy_kurs-5758.html#p81_TOC_idp1659892064
